# Convert date format from json data in the model and then pass to controller

Tags: swift, nsdateformatter

Here in my model I have a few struct to handle the data from server

```
struct Articles: Decodable {
var content : [ArticleData]

}

struct ArticleData: Decodable {
var title: String
var date_time: Date
var image: String
}
```

From the jason, I get a date, it's like that:

```
 "date_time": 1524842056.035,
```

First question:
I set the type of this type in model `Date` as you see in `ArticleData`, it that correct?

Then I read this json in the model something like that:

```
  guard let json = try? JSONDecoder().decode(Articles.self, from: data!) else {
   completion(.failure(loginError.networkError))
                return
            }

    completion(.success(json.content))
```

As you can see, I get an array from server `json.content` that contain title, date_time and image. I want to convert it here in the model and pass everything in `completion` to the controller. 
could you help me on that?

Thanks :)

Comment: Take a look at this link. https://useyourloaf.com/blog/swift-codable-with-custom-dates/

Comment: Thanks you so much

Comment: `decoder.dateDecodingStrategy = .secondsSince1970`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use type 'String' for your date and then convert it using dateFormatter or, use 'dateDecodingStrategy' function in your decoder. 
for passing the data you are already doing the correct thing. where ever you call the method you can get the model.

Comment: In the json that I get from server, there are another items as well (title and Image), in this case, I can use dateDecodingStrategy'? Or I have to get another json only for the date?

Comment: no you can use something like JSONDecoder(). dateDecodingStrategy = .formatYouUse then you are all set. but first create your decoder with var decoder = JSONDecoder(). then use this decoder to decode your data

Comment: Thanks for your help